# Is it correct to say "spendings"?

Tags: nouns, gerunds, singular-vs-plural

I've checked the word *spending* in many dictionaries and they all say it's uncountable. For example:

- [Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/spending?q=spending)
- [Collins English Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/spending)

However, I've seen many examples of *spending**s*** in corpora such as [COCA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/). For example:

> I think if you cut some government spendings and government itself, I
>   think this will trickle on down to people that really need help.

How can it be explained?

Comment: Its more common form is singular as an uncountable nouns, but there are numerous usages of spendings as a plural countable noun expecially in the mid-20th century. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=spendings&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cspendings%3B%2Cc0

Comment: government spending never takes s. You really need to trust native speakers here. Maybe in Indian English, I don't know. But in "standard" written English, the kind they use in schools and universities and in publications, spending never takes an s!

Comment: A lot of native speakers pluralize uncountable nouns if there is an implied unit of measurement.  Two waters -> two cups/bottles of water, for example.  I've not seen *spending* used that way, but we can maybe infer that it's meant to mean "categories of spending."

Comment: "Spendings" is a valid word but "expenditures" is the preferred term.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can pluralize an uncountable noun if there's an implied countable noun.

You can use the word "sands" as short for "types of sand". For example, "I've seen black sand and red sand. Of these two exotic sands, ..."

If two people at a table order water, you can refer to that as "two waters" rather than "two glasses of water" or two orders.

Here, "government spendings" is short for "instances of government spending". Instances of spending are countable.

Comment: I think this hits the nail on the head. If an author pluralizes _spendings_, I'll initially give the benefit of the doubt, and assume that, rather than being a typo or incorrect grammar, the author is talking about multiple kinds of distinct spending (such as military spending, educational spending, agricultural spending, health and human services spending, etc.)

Comment: @J.R. By far the most common usage of this kind of plural is for more than one kind or type. Using it to mean more than one instance is less common. I read this particular case as meaning instances, but it's hard to be sure without the full context.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Actually I first saw _spendings_ in a textbook in this sentence: "Give a brief account of the plan that you normally follow throughout a month for your spendings."

Comment: @Mori I understand that to mean something like "all of the instances in which you spend". But that may just be me.